# Erro com multiplas condições em IF

Tags: c, funções, algoritmo, variáveis

O if só procede se for 'm' o sexo da pessoa, se for os outros com `||` que eu coloquei não vai, alguém pode me tirar essa dúvida?

```
char sexo;
float altura, pesoideal;
printf("Qual o sexo da pessoa? \n");
scanf("%c", &sexo);

if ((sexo=='m') || (sexo=='homem') || (sexo=='masculino')) {
     printf("Qual a altura da pessoa? \n");
     scanf("%f", &altura);
     pesoideal=(72.7*altura)-58;
     printf("O peso ideal é %f", pesoideal);
}
```

Comment: Quando você declara `char sexo;` está reservando espaço de memória para *um* caractere. Quando tenta comparar com 'homem' ou 'masculino' está cometendo um erro. O caractere `'` serve para delimitar *um* caractere. Para uma string (um array de caracteres acrescido do caractere terminador '\0') utiliza-se o caractere`"` e as funções de tratamento de strings de <string.h>.

Comment: ((( valeu (: )))

Comment: Quer dizer q se eu usar  if ' char ', com essa aspa eu não posso denominar nenhum outro valor pra aquele char mesmo em outro if? ou a limitação do ' ' se aplica pra int ou float?

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. Dê uma estudada nos tipos de dados da linguagem C em algum material introdutório.

Comment: beleza, vou estudar mais